# Что делает конструкция «a.Tables["c", "d"]»?

Tags: c#

Может ли кто-то объяснить значение третьей строки в коде?

```
 Scripter scripter = new Scripter(myServer);
  Database db = myServer.Databases["my_db"];
  Table myTable = db.Tables["EmployeeAddress", "HumanResources"];

  ScriptingOptions scriptOptionsForDependendencies = new ScriptingOptions();

  scriptOptionsForDependendencies.WithDependencies = true;
  scriptOptionsForDependendencies.DriAll = true;
  StringCollection tableScripts = myTable.Script(scriptOptionsForDependendencies);

  foreach (string script in tableScripts)
  Console.WriteLine(script);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Database db = myServer.Databases["my_db"];
Table myTable = db.Tables["EmployeeAddress", "HumanResources"];
```

Получить таблицу `EmployeeAddress` в схеме `HumanResources` базы данных `my_db`.

---

Полезные ссылки:

1. [Generate Scripts for database objects with SMO for SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1833/generate-scripts-for-database-objects-with-smo-for-sql-server/)
2. [Scripter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx)
3. [Overview (SMO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162557.aspx)

Русской документации не встречал.